# ANN Train and Test set accuracy becomes 1.0 after second Epoch Keras Classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have the following classification model built

```
def build_classifier(input_size):
    
    hl_1_dim = int(input_size / 2)
    hl_2_dim = int(hl_1_dim / 2)
    
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(units = hl_1_dim, kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation='relu', input_dim = input_size))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = hl_2_dim, kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation='sigmoid') )
    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return classifier
```

that I supply a training set containing 20983 rows and 209 columns. All the values in the data set are normalized to [0,1] range.

To split the data set I use the `train_test_split` function like so:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.3, shuffle = True)
```

I train the model using these hyperparameters:

```
classifier = build_classifier(len(X_train[0]))
classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 50)
```

Regardless of any hyperparameter tuning I tried, whenever I form my problem as a classification problem, I get 1.0 accuracy both on test and training sets on second epoch out of 50. And loss from `binary_crossentropy` is always extremely small number in vicinity of 1.2403e-09. However, If I change the model to linear regression, I get more or less adequate loss using MSE as well as cross validation results:

```
def build_regressor(input_size):
    
    hl_1_dim = int(input_size / 2)
    hl_2_dim = int(hl_1_dim / 2)
    
    regressor = Sequential()
    regressor.add(Dense(units = hl_1_dim, kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation='relu', input_dim = input_size))
    regressor.add(Dense(units = hl_2_dim, kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation='relu'))
    regressor.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'normal') )
    #optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop()
    regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
    return regressor
```

Each row in my data set corresponds to an article from a news website, with various article parameters as columns like `doc2vec` vector representations of article's text and title, number of images/videos/iframes in the article, article's author, etc. as well as article views. The idea is to predict whether an article is going to be 'popular' based on the amount of views it gets.

To form this problem as a classification problem, I calculate the mathematical average (mean) of all the articles' views and if an article has  views higher than the average, then I add value of 1 for a 'Popular' column in my dataset. If an article's view count is lower than the average, I give it a value of 0.
So, the 'X' matrix of my dataset consists of all the upper mentioned values excluding the views count column (obviously, since the ANN would find the correlation between the view count and popularity).
The 'Y' array contains the values for 'Popular' column (1 or 0).
I use `sigmoid` activation function for the classifier model and `binary_crossentropy` for loss function.

For regression problem, I eliminate the 'Popular' column, and directly use the view count for values in Y array. I use `mean_squared_error` for loss function.

Optimizer is set to 'adam' for both regression and classification models.

For regression, I get around 2087 as loss of predicted Y values corresponding to `X_test` matrix using `mean_absolute_error()` of `sklearn.metrics`. Which is more or less what I would expect. But for the classifier, I get 1.0 accuracy and extremely low loss for training set,  as well as 1.0 accuracy for the test set.

I triple checked all the columns in the training set to make sure no column contains values that might give out a straight answer to whether the article is 'popular' or not. What might be the issue here?

Comment: Can you randomly assign the label and check if the classification loss is going to zero or not... if it is, then there is some error in the code, and if not, then there is some explicit relationship present in the dataset about the popularity

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried that just now, and the accuracy still goes to 1.0 on second epoch. I am unable to pinpoint the issue within the code since I use the same exact code for regression model except for activation function and loss function.

Comment: I dont see any issue in your code, Can you verify whether the test set has equal proportion of each class? You should cross check the data distribution between classes or otherwise, you can share reproducible code on google colab.